# Difference between normal Interface and MBean Interface

Tags: java, interface, jmx

I have doubt about the difference between normal Interface and MBean interface.

```
public interface TryMBean
{
    // method declaration
}

public class Try implements TryMBeans
{
    // method definition
}
```

this looks like a normal interface, but for this we are able to use jConsole to monitor. My doubt is, what is the difference so that we can monitor it, and how to get idea when to use normal interface and when to go for MBean. I am new to JMX.

Comment: read this about MBean interface https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2005/07/adding_informat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `MBean` interface *is* a regular interface. But it's definition follows some conventions, like it's name. The name of an MBean interface is supposed to end with `MBean`. Also, it defines its operations and attributes following some rules that are describe in the [Standard MBeans documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html)

Basically, if you want to create an MBean that can be used with a JMX console, you have to adhere to these rules. There are also other ways to create MBeans more dynamically that follows some other rules, e.g. if you're using Spring JMX, where MBeans can be dynamically generated based on a "regular" interface.

Comment: The latter has nothing to do with Spring per se, but is just a DynamicMBean. Great explanation otherwise.

Comment: Sure, @HeikoRupp, I was just giving Spring as an example that uses Dynamic MBeans. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using abstract classes if any of these statements apply to your situation:

In the java application, there are some related classes that need to share some lines of code then you can put these lines of code within the abstract class and this abstract class should be extended by all these related classes.
You can define the non-static or non-final field(s) in the abstract class so that via a method you can access and modify the state of the object to which they belong.
You can expect that the classes that extend an abstract class have many common methods or fields, or require access modifiers other than public (such as protected and private).
Consider using interfaces if any of these statements apply to your situation:

It is a total abstraction, All methods declared within an interface must be implemented by the class(es) that implements this interface.
A class can implement more than one interface. It is called multiple inheritances.
You want to specify the behavior of a particular data type but are not concerned about who implements its behavior.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).